# Regex only 14 numbers

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have the following text:

```
DiretorioXmlImpressao=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TESTE\\XmlImpressao\\08187168000160\\
```

I would like to select all but the CNPJ(14-character sentence at the end of the text), and so I tried the following regular expression:

```
DiretorioXmlImpressao=[^0-9]+
```

Returned:

```
DiretorioXmlImpressao=C:\\Program Files (x
```

but I expected: `08187168000160`

---

Sorry guys, i have a few experience with regex, I just don't express myself very well.

I want in fact do this return:

```
DiretorioXmlImpressao=C:\\Program Files (x)\\TESTE\\XmlImpressao\\
```

cause i want just only the 14-character and the \, for i can use in this replace. This is working execept when have numbers in the path like that"x86".

```
regexp_replace(teste,'DiretorioXmlImpressao=[^0-9]+',E'DiretorioXmlImpressao=P:\\TESTE\\XmlImpressao\\','ig');
```

the final expect result of my regex and replace is this below

```
DiretorioXmlImpressao=P:\\TESTE\\XmlImpressao\\08187168000160\\
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `/DiretorioXmlImpressao=.*?([0-9]+)\\$/`

Comment: You're telling your regex to get everything that is NOT a number 0-9. It's doing exactly what you told it to do...

Comment: If you need starting part only [also try like this](https://regex101.com/r/sA1zQ8/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've test this like bobble bubble said to do

```
DiretorioXmlImpressao=.*\D(?=\d)
```

and it's working like i wanted to

```
DiretorioXmlImpressao=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TESTE\\XmlImpressao\\
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a *tasteful* way to do this without a match group.

> select all but the 14-character sentence at the end of the text

means this to me (well, with the final backslashes added, as I'm assuming you'd want):

```
/^(.*)[0-9]{14}\\$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
/^(.*)([^\\]+\\?)$/
```

It'll return the part except the ending as first grouped match, and the ending part as the second.

If you do not want the second matched part, update the second group to:

```
/^(.*)(?:[^\\]+\\?)$/
```